# Script loops over and over again - why?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA newbie and tried to make two loops that work with an If-Statement - as per this code:

```
Sub Filter()
For Count = Worksheets("STR").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row To 1 Step -1
    For Counter = 5 To Worksheets("Filter").Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
    With Worksheets("STR").Range("C" & Count)
        If .Value Like Worksheets("Filter").Range("C" & Counter).Value _
            Or .Value Like Worksheets("Filter").Range("D" & Counter).Value _
            Or .Value Like Worksheets("Filter").Range("E" & Counter).Value _
            Or .Value Like Worksheets("Filter").Range("A" & Counter).Value Then
                Worksheets("STR").Range("D" & Count) = "X"
                'Worksheets("STR").Row("A" & Count).EntireRow.Delete
            Next Counter
        End If
    End With
Next Count
End Sub
```

At some stage I suppose it loops over and over again, until it crashes. The debugger tells me it's the "End If" Line, but I don't see what's wrong. Is there a way to make this easier?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As presented the code doesn't run - you would get a Next without For error because the `Next Counter` line should be after the `End If` and `End With` and not before them

Comment: Hey Barrowc, thx for that tip - but it still doesn't work (or takes REALLY long). Is there any way to make this perform better/at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four things

1. Indent your code. That will ensure that you don't make errors as @barrowc suggested.
2. I would suggest not to use `End(xlDown)` to find the last row. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) on how to find the last row.
3. Turn `ScreenUpdating` to False and set it back on.
4. Use Error handling

Your code after applying the above 4 suggestions will look like this.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Filter()
    Dim LastRowSTR As Long, LastRowFilter As Long
    
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    With Sheets("STR")
        LastRowSTR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Sheets("Filter")
        LastRowFilter = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    For Count = LastRowSTR To 1 Step -1
        For Counter = 5 To LastRowFilter
            With Worksheets("STR").Range("C" & Count)
                If .Value Like Worksheets("Filter").Range("C" & Counter).Value _
                Or .Value Like Worksheets("Filter").Range("D" & Counter).Value _
                Or .Value Like Worksheets("Filter").Range("E" & Counter).Value _
                Or .Value Like Worksheets("Filter").Range("A" & Counter).Value Then
                    Worksheets("STR").Range("D" & Count) = "X"
                    'Worksheets("STR").Row("A" & Count).EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        Next Counter
    Next Count
LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

INTERESTING READ.

**TOPIC: To ‘Err’ is Human**

**LINK**: http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/

Comment: +1 might want to throw in an `Option Explicit` at the top of the module if there isn't one there already

Comment: =1 for high-level customer service!

Comment: @barrowc: Yup very true. Added that.

Comment: ...and the `Option Explicit` means that `Count` and `Counter` need to be declared (unless they are in scope from somewhere else)